# Javascript passar mais de uma parâmetro

Tags: javascript

Tenho este código:

```
1 == a.redirect ? window.location = rootUrl + "/options/?welcome=true" : ($("#message").css("display", "block"), $("#message").html(a.message)), $("#signinButton").attr("value", "Entrar")
```

Gostaria de passar mais três parâmetros, mas não funciona, como faze-lo?

```
1 == a.redirect, a.firstparam, a.secondparam ? window.location = rootUrl + "/options/?welcome=true" : ($("#message").css("display", "block"), $("#message").html(a.message)), $("#signinButton").attr("value", "Entrar")
```

Eu tentei assim também:

```
1 == a.redirect ? window.location = rootUrl + "/options/?welcome=true" : ($("#message").css("display", "block"), $("#message").html(a.message)), $("#signinButton").attr("value", "Entrar")
```

Primeiro

```
2 == a.firstparam ? window.location = rootUrl + "/options/?welcome=true" : ($("#message").css("display", "block"), $("#message").html(a.message)), $("#signinButton").attr("value", "Entrar")
```

Segundo

```
3 == a.secondparam ? window.location = rootUrl + "/options/?welcome=true" : ($("#message").css("display", "block"), $("#message").html(a.message)), $("#signinButton").attr("value", "Entrar")
```

Mas nenhum funciona. Como faz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que o pretendes é isto `1 == (a.redirect && a.firstparam && a.secondparam) ?` […], ficando completo da seguinte forma:

```
1 == (a.redirect && a.firstparam && a.secondparam) ? window.location = rootUrl + "/options/?welcome=true" : ($("#message").css("display", "block"), $("#message").html(a.message)), $("#signinButton").attr("value", "Entrar")
```

Não o resto do código não testei, mas espero que isto ajude!

Comment: funcionou mas o *redirect* parou de funcionar...

Comment: Bom voltou funcionar não sei o que acontece... mas os Cookies criado no meu Json não vai junto com o redirect.

Comment: Parece-me que isso é outra questão. Envia código completo de forma a que se possa analisar e com melhor leitura. Como está está muito confuso não se percebe qual é a tua intenção.